# OSError : [Errno 38] Function not implemented - Django Celery implementation

Tags: centos, django, celery

I installed django-celery and I tried to start up the worker server but I get an OSError that a function isn't implemented.  I'm running CentOS release 5.4 (Final) on a VPS:

```
    . broker -> amqp://guest@localhost:5672/
    . queues ->
        . celery -> exchange:celery (direct) binding:celery
    . concurrency -> 4
    . loader -> djcelery.loaders.DjangoLoader
    . logfile -> [stderr]@WARNING
    . events -> OFF
    . beat -> OFF
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "manage.py", line 11, in <module>
 execute_manager(settings)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 438, in execute_manager
 utility.execute()
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 379, in execute
 self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 191, in run_from_argv
 self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 218, in execute
 output = self.handle(*args, **options)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django_celery-2.0.0-py2.6.egg/djcelery/management/commands/celeryd.py", line 22, in handle
 run_worker(**options)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/celery-2.0.1-py2.6.egg/celery/bin/celeryd.py", line 385, in run_worker
 return Worker(**options).run()
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/celery-2.0.1-py2.6.egg/celery/bin/celeryd.py", line 218, in run
 self.run_worker()
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/celery-2.0.1-py2.6.egg/celery/bin/celeryd.py", line 312, in run_worker
 worker.start()
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/celery-2.0.1-py2.6.egg/celery/worker/__init__.py", line 206, in start
 component.start()
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/celery-2.0.1-py2.6.egg/celery/concurrency/processes/__init__.py", line 54, in start
 maxtasksperchild=self.maxtasksperchild)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/celery-2.0.1-py2.6.egg/celery/concurrency/processes/pool.py", line 448, in __init__
 self._setup_queues()
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/celery-2.0.1-py2.6.egg/celery/concurrency/processes/pool.py", line 564, in _setup_queues
 self._inqueue = SimpleQueue()
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 315, in __init__
 self._rlock = Lock()
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/multiprocessing/synchronize.py", line 117, in __init__
 SemLock.__init__(self, SEMAPHORE, 1, 1)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/multiprocessing/synchronize.py", line 49, in __init__
 sl = self._semlock = _multiprocessing.SemLock(kind, value, maxvalue)
 OSError
 :
[Errno 38] Function not implemented
```

Am I just totally screwed and should use a new kernel that has this implemented or is there an easy way to resolve this?